# ASPxCallbackPanel - Catching Exact Exception Statement on CallbackError When Custom Error Page is Used

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

***Application Logic Details:***

We are using a **CustomErroPage** in our Application which is defined in **"web.config"** file of the Application. Following is the Tag in web.config file

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/COM/Forms/ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On"/></system.web>
```

**Here the "mode" can have Values "On or Off "**

So **whenever some Error/Exception comes then application redirects the User to the ErrorPage. And somehow we are able to Log the Error in the System Logs of Application and from the Logs we can easily find out what problem has occurred.**

Actually, we have also Implemented the ASPxCallbackPanel for Partial postbacks in some cases so that Page should not load Completely.

In case of ASPxCallbackPanel, **I am handling the event "ClientSideEvents-CallbackError" to get the Error Message and Log it into the System Logs to rectify the Problem from Log Details.**

***Problem:***

**If 
 ( mode = "On" )**  then In Callback Error Event,  Message is coming (Some Internal Server Error Occurred during Callback)
**else if
 ( mode = "Off" )**  then In Callback Error Event,  Actual Error is Coming with Details e.g. Some Value is null etc

***Solution Required:***

Please let me know, Is it Possible to **Catch the Exact Statement of Exception in "ClientSideEvents-CallbackError" with (mode = "On")**

Share your thoughts if someone has some idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to proceed with the steps listed in the [How to use the ASPxWebControl.CallbackError event to handle application-level errors occurred inside ASPxWebControls during callback processing](https://www.devexpress.com/example=E2398) example. The main idea is the follows:

- Subscribe to the special server-side **ASPxWebControl.CallbackError** event in **Global.asax -> Application_Start** (for example, use the existing **Application_Error** handler for all errors).
- Capture DevExpress callback errors along with the remaining errors.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail..
I have achieved the solution almost the same way.. :)